# How to find MAX number in unseen array using for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is the solution to the problem. What I don't understand is why is it not "if ( i > currentMax)? I also don't understand the nature of numbers[i]. I understand we can reference indexes in arrays doing numbers[0], but numbers[i] is confusing me.

```
function max(numbers) {

  let currentMax = numbers[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > currentMax) {
      currentMax = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  return currentMax;
}
```

Comment: `Math.max(...numbers)`

Comment: numbers[i] is exactly as numbers[0] in your example. it is inside a for loop where i will become a number from 0 to the max lenght of numbers. so each time the loop will be executed it will be numbers[0], then numbers[1] and so on

Comment: After re-reading your question, it seems like you need to do some reading up on [JavaScript Loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to understand what `i` is and why it is used the way it is.

Comment: @mhodges OP has found somewhere this code that does what he wants but he has no clue why... agree with you about the fact that he needs to learn a lot

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yeah, that's why I posted the link. I misread the question at first, I thought it was asking how to find the max without using a loop.

Comment: @mhodges btw good solution on your side :-)

Answer (score 1):

`numbers[i]` refers to the value stored at position `i`. If you were to use `if (i > currentMax)` then you would always return the last element, since the last element always has the greatest index.

Don't reinvent the wheel, use `Math.max(...numbers)`.

Comment: Reinventing wheels is sometikes useful, especially when learning how things work.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `i` is an "index" which allows us to iterate over all the positions in the array (and accessing their values). In this case `i=0`, `i=1`,..., `i=numbers.length`,

`if (numbers[i] > currentMax)` asks if the number stored in the array in the position `i` is greater than the `currentMax` value. This guarantees that **from the provided array the maximum number is returned**.

If you ask `if (i > currentMax)` you compare the value of the "index" (`i`) with the value of the `currentMax` value. This is incorrect if you want to return the greatest value from an array of numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't call `i` a pointer. That could be misleading since it doesn't point to a position in memory; it's just an integer that's used as an index.

Comment: @bstrauch24 but its a slightly related concept, and I don't think that this is a matter here

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array like:

```
[1, 2, 4, 2]
```

This starts by setting `currentMax` `numbers[0]` which is one. Then it loops through the array one element at a time. If it finds a larger number during that loop — in other words `if (numbers[i] > currentMax)` then it sets the `currentMax` that number instead. For example this will happen the second and thirds times through the loop when `i` equals 2 & 4. But it won't happen the last time through the loop. An easy way to watch this happen is to print some stuff to the console as it runs:

```js
function max(numbers) {

  let currentMax = numbers[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    console.log("i:", i, "element:", numbers[i], "max:", currentMax)
    if (numbers[i] > currentMax) {
      currentMax = numbers[i];
      console.log("new currentMax:", currentMax)
    }
  }
  return currentMax;
}

max([1, 2, 4, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you can reference indexes in arrays by doing numbers. Instead of hard coding numbers you can use a variable that has a number as a value.

```
function max(numbers) {
  // get the value in the first place in the array  
  let currentMax = numbers[0];

  // create a variable called i
  // set it to 0
  // loop through, increasing i each time, for as long as i is less than the length of the array
  // the first time through i = 0
  // the second time through i = 1
  // then i = 2
  // ... repeat until the end
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    // get the value from the array at the i place
    // if it is greater than the current max
    if (numbers[i] > currentMax) {
      // then set current max to it
      currentMax = numbers[i];
    }
  }

  // return current max
  return currentMax;
}
```